# Error 404 al intentar descargar PDF - ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito descargar un PDF que tengo almacenado dentro de una carpeta en mi aplicación, quiero que se abra en una pestaña nueva.
El siguiente código me funciona perfecto en mi aplicación local pero una vez publicada en el servidor e intentar descargar el archivo lanza el error:

> 'error 404 archivo o página no encontrada'

Código que funciona en mi aplicación local pero no en el servidor:

```
protected void Manual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('/ModuloGeneral/ImpresionConf/Manual.pdf'),'_blank')", true);
        }
```

Probé también agregando el ñuflo adelante de la url pero tampoco funciona:

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('~/ModuloGeneral/ImpresionConf/Manual.pdf'),'_blank')", true);
```

y de esta manera tampoco funciona:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('~\\ModuloGeneral\\ImpresionConf\\Manual.pdf'),'_blank')", true);
```

Dejo el .aspx del LinkButton que uso para descargar el archivo:

```
<td colspan="7" align="center">                     
   <asp:LinkButton ID="Manual" runat="server" class="lnkDocumento" OnClick="Manual_Click">Manual</asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
</td>
```

Comment: Tu aplicación está corriendo en un directorio virtual o como un sitio?

Comment: Como un sitio, yo creo que el error puede estar en la lectura de la url, por eso probé de varias formas pero no logro que el servidor la reconozca.

Comment: Si es un sitio, La solución es `/ModuloGeneral/ImpresionConf/Manual.pdf` y un 404 es que el archivo simplemente no está ahi.

Comment: Claro, de esa manera funciona en mi aplicación local, pero luego de publicarla en el servidor no reconoce la url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente el problema era la lectura de la URL por parte del servidor, tuve que usar el tipo de sintaxis literal para que la ruta de la URL pueda ser leída.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", @"window.open('\ImpresionConf\\Manual.pdf','_blank')", true);
```

Dejo un link sobre el manejo de cadenas por si a alguien le sirve que es donde obtuve la información:  [Cadenas_C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/).